# Making Activity with several ViewPagers

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Im trying to make an Activity that contains several View's added to LinearLayout inside ScrollView.Those View's are layout files inflated with LayoutInflater,and they contain TextView and ViewPager(that uses FragmentPagerAdapter).The problem is that only the first ViewPager shows fragments, and other ViewPagers just empty.

MainActivity.class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

       for(int i = 0;i<10;i++) {

        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(new FragmentRed());
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(new FragmentYellow());
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(new FragmentGreen());

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test_item, null);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText("SampleText " + i);

        linearLayout.addView(view);
    }

    private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        ArrayList<Fragment>fragments = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment){
            fragments.add(fragment);
        }

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }
    }
```

And this is what i get in the emulator :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKFYM.jpg

First ViewPager works fine, and i need to make others do so.

test_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to explain, but I will try my best.

Array lists don't work the same way int, String, bools... work. If you declare a array list the way you declare it points to the same Fragments.
An ArrayList can contain multiple references to the same exact object.

I think that you will solve your problem by simply:

```
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++) {

        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(new FragmentRed());
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(new FragmentYellow());
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(new FragmentGreen());

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test_item, null);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText("SampleText " + i);

        linearLayout.addView(view);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I edited the code like you suggested, but i'm still having the same problem;Only one viewPager has fragments in it.